# UWP How to define DataTemplate in App.XAML

Tags: win-universal-app

I Want to define Datatemplate in App.XAML and then shared it for any page i need to use this itemtemplate. I don't know how to do it

Comment: How you do it in normal page, can you show some code? Have you tried to do it in the mentioned file in *Application.Resources*?

Answer (score 16):

It depends on the type of binding, you want to use.

If you're using **standard XAML binding**, everything is the same as in WPF:

1. Define the template in `Application.Resources`:

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
       <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop1}" />
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Prop2}" />
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </Application.Resources>
   ```
2. Reference the template in the page:

   ```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template1}" />
   ```

If you're using **compiled `{x:bind}` binding**, you'll need to define the templates in a separate resource dictionary with code behind where the generated code will end up:

1. Create a new partial class for the resource dictionary:

   ```
   public partial class DataTemplates
   {
       public DataTemplates()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a resource dictionary based on this partial class with the data template:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:local="using:MyNamespace"
       x:Class="MyNamespace.DataTemplates">

       <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2" x:DataType="local:MyClass">
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Prop1}" />
               <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Prop2}" />
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
3. Merge the resource dictionary into `Application.Resources`:

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <local:DataTemplates/>
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
   ```
4. Finally use the template in the page:

   ```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template2}" />
   ```

You can check [Igor's blog post](http://igrali.com/2015/06/14/how-to-use-compiled-bindings-xbind-from-a-resource-dictionary/) for more details. Nothing significant has changed since the preview when the post was published.

Comment: Is there any particular advantage doing this instead of just defining a custom control that takes the desired `x:DataType` as a property parameter and is put inside of the `<DataTemplate/>` tag?