# How do I consistently bind a ViewModel to a View?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, winui

In WinUI or UWP XAML, how do I consistently bind a specific type of ViewModel to a specific View? (This is a follow-up to [Should UserControls expose arbitrary properties or just a ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75794390/788168)).

### Example

For example, let's take this [basic card from Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/#basic-card):

[image: a basic card]

Per the advice in [Should UserControls expose arbitrary properties or just a ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75794390/788168), I've made a control like this:

```xml
<Card
    Subtitle="Word of the Day"
    Title="Be*nev*o*lent"
    LowerSubtitle="adjective"
    Description="well meaning and kindly. 'a benevolent smile'"
    LinkText="Learn more"
    LinkUri="http://example.com" />
```

I also know that my team will be using this `Card` with a specific ViewModel, `WordOfTheDayViewModel`, a lot:

```
runtimeclass WordOfTheDayViewModel: Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    WordOfTheDayViewModel();
    String Word{ get; };
    String PartOfSpeech{ get; };
    String Definition{ get; };
    Uri DefinitionUri{ get; };
}
```

It'll be bound like this:

```xml
<Card
    Subtitle="Word of the Day"
    Title="{x:Bind ViewModel.Word}"
    LowerSubtitle="{x:Bind ViewModel.PartOfSpeech}"
    Description="{x:Bind ViewModel.Definition}"
    LinkText="Learn more"
    LinkUri="{x:Bind ViewModel.DefinitionUri}" />
```

In this hypothetical example, this will happen a lot in many places---we'll need to show this card bound to the same type of viewmodel (with different instances) in many places. **Can I write code to standardize this binding**, so my team doesn't have to rewrite these 7 lines each time?

### Potential answers

From what I gather, there are a few potential answers, but I'm not sure how to pick:

- **Don't standardize this binding**: have the team bind the `WordOfTheDayViewModel` to the `Card` every time it's used. "You're likely going to need to repeat that code less than you think, and there will probably be *required* subtle differences each time you bind it."
- **Create another `UserControl`**: create a new `UserControl`, like `<WordOfTheDayCard Word="">` that takes a `WordOfTheDayViewModel` and does this binding behind the scenes. "The overhead of another `UserControl` is not a huge issue in this case (?)."
- **Some sort of weird functional binding thing I can't fathom**: in React, I'd simply write a transformer function that maps my `WordOfTheDayViewModel` to well-formed `Card`s (see example below). The overhead is straightforward: one additional function call. "WinUI can do this too, you just don't know it."
- **A standard `ItemTemplate` in my `ResourceDictionary`**: Not even sure if that's possible?
- **Something else entirely**: By all means!

---

(Here's what I'd write in React):

```js
// wow, so cheap! much virtual DOM
function WordCard(word: WordOfTheDayViewModel): JSX.Element {
    return <Card
        Subtitle="Word of the Day"
        Title={word.Word}
        LowerSubtitle={word.PartOfSpeech}
        Description={word.Definition}
        LinkText={Learn more}
        LinkUri={word.DefinitionUri}>;
}
```

---

Comment: You can use a DataTemplate, they can be shared https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811571/uwp-how-to-define-datatemplate-in-app-xaml

Comment: The first option of "Don't standardize this binding" would be right choice IMO. You don't want a control to be tied to a specific view model. That's the point of defining a standalone control in the first place, i.e. that you can use it with different view models.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **CardInfo** `class` or `record`,

```cs
record CardInfo(string Title, string SubTitle, string Description, string Uri);
```

then create a `Style` so you won't need to repeat **SubTitle** and **LinkText** settings,

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Card">
        <Setter Property="SubTitle" Value="Word of the day" />
        <Setter Property="LinkText" Value="Learn more" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

finally add a **CardInfo** ``DependencyProperty in your **Card** control and use it like this,

```xml
<Card CardInfo="{x:Bind ViewModel.CardInfo}" />
```

Comment: Do I no longer have a generic `Card` UserControl that supports arbitrary `Title`s, etc?

Comment: You can have all the "related" properties in **CardInfo**, including "SubTitle" and "LinkText". But in this case, if you need to change a single property, the **Description** for example, you'll need to set a new **CardInfo** in order to make UI updated.